# Data resolution change in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe whose data has a resolution of 10 minutes as seen below:

```
                  DateTime   TSM
0      2011-03-18 14:20:00  26.8
1      2011-03-18 14:30:00  26.5
2      2011-03-18 14:40:00  26.3
...                    ...   ...
445088 2019-09-03 11:40:00  27.6
445089 2019-09-03 11:50:00  27.6
445090 2019-09-03 12:00:00  27.6
```

Now, I would like to reduce its resolution to 1 day. Does Pandas have any function that can help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried `resample` method?

Comment: I'm trying, but i got this: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataframe should have datetime index in order to use  `resample` method. Also you need to apply an aggregate function, for example `mean()`

```
# Make sure DateTime type is datetime
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].astype('datetime64')

# Set DateTime column as index
df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)

# 1D stands for 1 day offset
df.resample('1D').mean()
```